# Does anyone know how i can include sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer; in a code i am running on Windows ?

Tags: eclipse, maven, java

I am using a Java Application that has a package for mac as well so when I run the code in my eclipse I am not able to resolve classes like 
    import sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer;
    import sun.lwawt.PlatformWindow;
    import sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow; 
in it, as I am trying to run this application in my Eclipse running on my Windows OS. I am running Java jdk 1.7 for Windows.  I couldnt find where this library is and what dependency i must add in my Maven for these packages.. Does anyone know this? Can you help me? Sorry if this is a trivial question but i am newbie to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it can't be done. XXXPeer classes were a part of Java 1.0 (pre swing) that involve creating native OS UI components to use in Java. The classes that implement this are written using JNI (ie C++ / not java) and are not cross platform compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much . That  makes sense. So since I am running on my Windows these classes dont take any effect on my application so I guess i can do away with it not being resolved. However, I am curious if this application is loaded on Mac , will these imports be resolved automatically ?

Comment: @ Ramya It depends what comes in the JRE. But I'd think probably yes. And if not, you've got the same issue you'd have trying to use this on Windows or Unix